# Dart doc puts everything under same " folder " called libraries

Tags: dart, dartdoc

When using dart doc, it puts all my source code files under the same " folder " - libraries. E.g
I have file "A.dart" in lib/directoryA and file "B.dart" in lib/directoryB. Both of them are just listed as:

**Libraries**

- A.dart
- B.dart

Is there any way to actually tell dart doc that there are in different directories? E.g:

**Libraries**

- DirectoryA

  - A.dart
- DirectoryB

  - B.dart